# Flying Saucer in Lotus Notes

Tags: java, itext, lotus-notes, lotus

I was trying to convert simple XHTML-files to PDF, and used Flying Saucer and iText to do so. It worked without problems in Java, however, when I tried to make a Lotus Notes agent with the same code, I got an exception I am unsure how to deal with.

The code:

```
import lotus.domino.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer; 
import org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRLog;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaAgent extends AgentBase {

    public void NotesMain() {

      try {
        Session session = getSession();
        AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
        String received = agentContext.getDocumentContext().
             getItemValueString("Query_String");
        String[] split;
        split = received.split("&");
        String url = split[1];
        split = url.split("/");
        String outputFile = split[split.length-1];
        String direc = session.getEnvironmentString("Directory", true);
        outputFile = direc + "\\" + outputFile + ".pdf"; 
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.setDocument(url);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);
        os.close();
        System.exit(0);

      } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

This yields the following:

> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM: Could not initialize configuration for Flying Saucer library. Message is: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key access_properties_not_allowed
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key access_properties_not_allowed
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM:    at java.util.MissingResourceException.(MissingResourceException.java:50)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM:    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:400)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM:    at java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:421)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM:    at lotus.notes.JavaString.getString(Unknown Source)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:29   HTTP JVM:    at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:30   HTTP JVM:    at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:323)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:30   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.Configuration.loadSystemProperties(Configuration.java:419)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:30   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.Configuration.(Configuration.java:147)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:30   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.Configuration.instance(Configuration.java:742)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.Configuration.valueFor(Configuration.java:463)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.Configuration.isTrue(Configuration.java:709)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRLog.init(XRLog.java:250)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRLog.log(XRLog.java:203)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRLog.render(XRLog.java:194)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRLog.render(XRLog.java:190)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.SharedContext.(SharedContext.java:107)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.(ITextRenderer.java:111)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.(ITextRenderer.java:102)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at JavaAgent.NotesMain(Unknown Source)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
>
> 09-05-2011 13:33:31   HTTP JVM:    at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

The offending line is

```
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
```

Googling "access_properties_not_allowed" gives literally nothing.

Answer (score 5):

1) Agents in Notes/Domino have an additional security feature in the Agent properties that sets the security level of the agent.  By default, this setting is set to not allow restricted operations (the default setting is "Do not allow restricted operations").

In order for the agent to run the property it must be set to one of the following options:

"Allow restricted operations"
"Allow restricted operations with full administration rights"

The property is found on the second tab, the key tab, of the Agent Properties dialog box.

2) As "road to yamburg" already explained, the JVM's Security Manager is not allowing access to the system's properties because the security policy does not specify to allow this action.
You must change the security policy of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) in order to allow access to the system properties.  To do this, you can add the line "permission java.security.AllPermission;" to the "/jvm/lib/security/java.policy" file in the Notes/Domino directory.

The java.policy file will look similar to this after making the change:

```
grant { 
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.version", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.vendor.url", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "java.class.version", "read";
    permission java.util.PropertyPermission "os.name", "read";
        // ... and so on ...
}
```

Once the client/server is restarted, any Java program requiring access to System.getProperties() will now be granted access.

Comment: The agent properties were right already, but changing the data policy did the trick - thank you (and road to yamburg) for the advice. (The file's directory was called Lotus/Domino though)

Comment: @jmhajek So please accept this answer as the correct one, so we can easily see the issue has been solved. See [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). ;)

Comment: permission java.security.AllPermission; is going to stop all the security on the server. AFAIK the least you could do would be to restrict this to the one database.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely the security configuration:

XhtmlRenderer tries to read its configuration from System properties:

```
09-05-2011 13:33:30 HTTP JVM: at java.lang.System.getProperties(System.java:323)
09-05-2011 13:33:30 HTTP JVM: at org.xhtmlrenderer.util.Configuration.loadSystemProperties(Configuration.java:419)
```

But it is not allowed (SecurityManager),

```
09-05-2011 13:33:29 HTTP JVM: at lotus.notes.AgentSecurityManager.checkPropertiesAccess(Unknown Source)
```

There must be an exception thrown, caught and an error message needs to be produced. That error message have to be loaded from a resource bundle, but the bundle is not found.

```
09-05-2011 13:33:29 HTTP JVM: Could not initialize configuration for Flying Saucer library. Message is: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key access_properties_not_allowed
```

Solution:

- Try to find security properties for Lotus Domino JVM (don't know where they may be or should be), and let the code to read system properties

Or

- Make a patch to org.xhtmlrenderer package to catch security exceptions and handle them on their own.

Comment: I've seen this type of error before on external libraries that use reflection and I think road-to-yamburg is correct. I assume you're using this as java agent that responds to a post (called from webquerysave?).

You can get access to more fine grained security if you store the external jar files on the server filesystem in /jvm/lib/ext rather than in the database, then modify the permissions with the java.policy file. [This post](http://lekkimworld.com/2006/04/25/java_in_notes_domino_explained_security_201.html) has more info about java security in Domino.